# Mysql: get first login and last log out timings

Tags: mysql, sql

was tryin to get first login and last logout of an employee
my data looks like

sample fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4deb0/1

in emp_timings

```
userid  type        swipe_time
1,     'in_time',   '2019-10-21 09:10:20' 
1,     'out_time',  '2019-10-21 11:20:50'
1,     'in_time',   '2019-10-21 13:10:20'
1,     'out_time',  '2019-10-21 20:20:50'
2,     'out_time',  '2019-10-21 09:00:30'
2,     'in_time',   '2019-10-21 10:10:10'
2,     'out_time',  '2019-10-21 11:30:30'
2,     'in_time',   '2019-10-21 13:10:10'
2,     'out_time',  '2019-10-21 21:30:30'

 emp table
 userid   name
 1,      'Albert'
 2,      'Edison'
```

and was looking for an output like below

```
userid  name       in_time                 out_time   
1       Albert     '2019-10-21 09:10:20'   '2019-10-21 20:20:50'
2       Edison     '2019-10-21 10:10:10'   '2019-10-21 21:30:30'
```

to achieve this first I was trying to get the first in_time like below

```
select min(swipe_time) swipe_in, userid, type, swipe_time, date(swipe_time)
from emp_timings
where type = 'in_time' and  date(`swipe_time`) = CURDATE()
group by userid, swipe_time
```

but ended with multiple time

Comment: Do you want the first time the employee logs-in ever, or the first time the employee logs-in on a given day? Basically, my question is "what if the `swipe_time` ad different days, what would the expected result be?"

Comment: in a given day.

Comment: Probably learning how to use proper `GROUP BY` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select et.userid,
       min(case when et.type = 'in_time' then et.swipe_time end) as swipe_in,         
       max(case when et.type = 'out_time' then et.swipe_time end) as swipe_out
from emp_timings et
where et.swipe_time >= curdate() and
      et.swipe_time < curdate + interval 1 day
group by et.userid;
```

I leave it up to you to join in the name.

Note that the date comparisons have changed.  Although your method is perfectly valid, it prevents the query from using an index on `swipe_time`, if an appropriate index is available.  The revised code is index-friendly.

Comment: little curious to know, how to get the same across different dates, so that a monthly report be generated

Comment: @x-code . . . New questions should be asked as *new* questions.  Spanning multiple dates actually brings up other issues.  Do you want one row per date or per month?  What if the last swipe of the day is an `in`?  You should ask a new question with appropriate explanation and data.